# Авторизация на сайте через POST запрос, ошибка 403

Tags: python, post, auth, requests

Пример моего кода:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
data = {"username":"login", "pass":"pass"}
url = "https://admin.clickVKsa.com/login.php"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Safari/537.36'}

r = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print(r) #Response 403
```

Форма регистрации:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="login.php">
    
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="width: 400px; margin-top:20px;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="td_title">Members entrance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Логин</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Пароль</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br/>

    <div class="button_green_container">
        <div class="button_left_side"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Переход"  class="button_right_side" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="9a927c824929f0688c8ccc9bd747928bd749ab11">
</form>
```

В результате выполнения, вместо авторизации и кода 200, получаю код 403. Что необходимо исправить для корректной авторизации?

Comment: Без информации о процессе авторизации на сервере ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Прежде всего, о сервисе "https://admin.clickVKsa.com/login.php". Если есть возможность (я так понимаю, это что-то своё) - было бы хорошо показать его исходный код. Ну и больше информации об ответе сервиса (в первую очередь, заголовки), а не только статус.

Comment: Проблема решилась, необходимо было в data добавить текущий 'csrf_token' и добавить в headers 'Referer':***.

Comment: csrf_token еще дублируется в куки

Comment: @djflkpy если нашли решение, опубликуйте его ввиду ответа. [Это поощряется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)